# How to Remove | from data in excel

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with the data, one column had values with line breakers, I used Find and replace to remove line breakers and replace with `|`. Now I want to remove/replace `|` but unable to do. Or is it  possible to make the groups of `|` into one, see the sample data below:

```
     A        
   ||This text 1| | this text 2|||| this text 3|||| 
   ||This text 5| | this text 4|||| this text 6||||
```

I tried to search and replace but it's not working.

Comment: what do you mean "not working"?  There are about 20 different ways you could remove those (including search and replace), depending on what you want to do with it afterwards.

Comment: When I try to replace || or |||| with single |, it does not happen.

Comment: What are you trying to replace the vertical bars with?

Comment: Why do you need one there still?  what is the end goal?

Comment: Can you share with us the expected output? You need that part to have [mcve]

Comment: When I copy and paste || in the "find and replace" just one | is pasted with a white space. If I try to copy |||| just one | gets copied with 3 white spaces. If I type it manually, it does not find any thing. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @zipa i want to split data by using text to column tool, but ||| make lot of empty cells, so I want to make them just one so that I can achieve my target output.

Comment: Have you ticked the box next to `Treat consecutive delimiters as one`?

Comment: Thanks @zipa its work .. thanks for help.

Comment: Added it as an answer, in case you want to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to tick the box next to `Treat consecutive delimiters as one`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably that you're not realizing how many spaces there are in between.  Worksheet function `TRIM` removes anything more than single spaces (on the ends or within the string).

Combine that with SUBSTITUTE (or Find & Replace) to get it cleaner:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),"||","|")
```

with your examples you'd need to run it a few times or nest them:

[image: img]

Really your ***actual problem*** is how you generated this text.  **Instead of trying to find a workaround to the solution, you should try to fix the problem at the source.**
[image: img]

**Formula in B2:**

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A2),"| |","|"),"||","|"),"||","|")`

---

Or if using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, start with the longest strings first and `Replace All` repeatedly until there are no more matches, then move onto the next longest:

Comment: Thanks for help and your time i tried this formula, but in Output i got same values, i dont know why but i dont get values like your above.

Comment: Are you using the same data as me???  ...or is your example not actually representative of the *actual* data?   But more importantly, did you create this file yourself in a different application?  (See the bottom note of my answer - I believe this is what's known as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)... asking how to fix your perceived solution as opposed to how to fix the problem.. not your fault, it's very common.)

Comment: Sorry for my bad question and format, i use this method to get that data.  Replace or remove line breaks with the search function

    Open the search window by pressing Ctrl + f on the keyboard.
    Type Ctrl + j into the search field and press Enter .
    As the “Replace with” value enter a space character .
    Click on “Replace All” or just “Replace” if you want to go cell by cell.  hope this make some sens

Comment: back up.  back waaay up.   What data, from where?

Comment: ah nevermind, you got the answer figured out right above right?  Whatever it is you're exporting from somewhere, google how to do that better. Automation is supposed to decrease repetition, not increase it